# Angular js factory injection

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular JS. I have created factory as follows.

```
angular.module('login',[])
        .factory('authFactory',[function(){
         // logic 

        }] );
```

and have injected into controller, but it gives me an error.

I also provided this factory file in index.html, but the error is the same.

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: authFactoryProvider <- authFactory

What should I do to avoid this?

Below is the code where I have injected it.

```
(function () {
  'use strict';


  angular.module('login', []).controller("LoginController", loginController)

  loginController.$inject = ['$cookies', '$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', '$window',authFactory];

  function loginController($cookies, $log, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $location, $timeout, $window,authFactory) {
```

Comment: Show the code you have injected it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this? (you are missing '')

```
loginController.$inject = ['$cookies', '$log', '$scope', 
    '$rootScope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', '$window', 'authFactory'];
```

Don't create module twice:

```
angular.module('login', [])
    .factory('authFactory',[function(){
     // logic 

    }] )

angular.module('login').controller("LoginController", loginController)
```

Comment: (you are missing '') , where ?

Comment: @prasad : In your controller loginController.$inject = ['$cookies', '$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', '$window',authFactory]; The last injected service authFactory should be annotated as 'authFactory' such that it should look like  loginController.$inject = ['$cookies', '$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', '$window','authFactory'];

Answer (score 0):

Don't use module twice make it as your practice to code like this

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var login = angular.module('login',[]);

  login.factory('authFactory',[function(){
         // logic 
    return {
    }

  }]);

  login.controller("LoginController", loginController);

  loginController.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', '$window','authFactory'];

  function loginController($log, $scope, $rootScope, $q, $location, $timeout, $window,authFactory) {

  }

})();
```

As you are new to angular, i would recommend you to go through this youtube video which is very good

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDhGmFul4YU&index=2&list=PLvZkOAgBYrsS_ugyamsNpCgLSmtIXZGiz